# Import element from large excel file

Tags: import, excel

I am trying to import some rows and columns from a large excel file, but I get this error

> There was insufficient Java heap space for the operation. Try
>   increasing the Java Virtual Machine heap size.

What's interesting, is that this error shows up even if I try to import just a cell from the file, like

```
Import["path/to/file.xls", {"Data", 1, 1, 1}]
```

It still gives an error. That seems wrong, since a single cell does not take any space in memory!

Comment: `Import` internally imports the whole thing before extracting the part.  You may even do better to simply do `Import["file.xls"][[1,1,1]]`

Comment: @george2079 Wow, that's crazy inefficient!

Comment: sure is.  Might make the same comment about storing large data in excel in the first place :-)

Comment: @george2079 Not my fault. It was handed to me this way. Regrettably many people seem to like this format, I do not.

Comment: It is large with many sheets, or a single sheet is large? Splitting each sheet up into its own file might not be too difficult.

Comment: If you actually want to try increasing the heap size: `ReinstallJava[JVMArguments -> "-Xmx16000m"]` for e.g. 16 GB of memory.